# XSLT - output select elements and skip rest

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new to XSLT. I am trying to use XSLT to convert XML to CSV. I have looked at the various online examples available and also tried to figure it out on my own however I have been struggling to get the desired result. Any help would be appreciated.

Now the problem statement.
I have the below XML which I want to convert to CSV. The catch here is that I want to copy data only from a select node and its children nodes and ignore the rest of the nodes.

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <WorkInfo>
        <Skill>Java</Skill>
        <Experience>10</Experience>
        <PreviousCompany>XYZ</PreviousCompany>
    </workInfo>
    <PersonalInfo>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <LastName> Trevor</LastName>
        <Age>35</Age>
    </PersonalInfo>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

I want to print the data under node *WorkInfo* and its children nodes only and not print *PersonalInfo* and its children.

I am using the below the xslt

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="workInfo"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="PersonalInfo"/>
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="workInfo">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="PersonalInfo">
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

However I am not getting the expected output, which is

```
Java,10,XYZ
```

But end up getting an empty result. Please can someone help me understand where I am going wrong.

Thanks,
LTL

Comment: If you have a `WorkInfo` element then you need to match and select on that name and not on the `workInfo`.There are more issues like outputting the children comma separated and making sure `WorkInfo` is selected with the right path (it is not a child of the document node).

Answer (score 0):

Please modify the XSL template as below. You need to loop through all the child elements of `WorkInfo` and output their values using `<xsl:value-of>`.

```
<xsl:template match="Employee">
    <xsl:for-each select="WorkInfo/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Output

```
Java,10,XYZ
```